# How to install openJDK 8 on 17.04 LTS?

Tags: apt, package-management, java, openjdk

When I ran this command:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

I keep getting this:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process

Answer (score 1):

Another process uses dpkg.

1.So if such process is running , wait to be finished.

2.If it's not work , system restart may be helpful.

3.And if any of them not be helpful , try this command:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

4.Also you may need this commands:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

Comment: Thank you! Restarting my computer and using the first command worked!

Comment: @Aurora Thanks ; If it be helpful , Please accept this answer.